# vscode unable to read docker-compose extension

Tags: docker, macos, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

Running docker desktop for mac m1. which doesn't had docker compose by default. I installed docker-compose separately.

I have a docker-compse.yml file which my devcontainer(devcontainer.json) is pointing to.

> "dockerComposeFile": "../docker-compose.yml"

below works fine

> docker-compose up

however, vscode is unable to open dev container by reading docker-compose.yml file, since it complains "Docker Compose required"

Is there a way to ask vscode to use docker-compose which installed manually ?

NOTE -

- docker compose plugin comes with docker, which runs via `docker compose`
- however, manually installed runs `docker-compose`.